# How do I convert a mathematical Microsoft Word document to a WordPress blog post?

Tags: posts, blog, microsoft, latex

I have a Microsoft Word document which I would like to convert to WordPress.

The document is in Hebrew. It contains mathematical equations generated with [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/). It also contains images.

Just copying and pasting the text of the document to the text area (in WordPress control pannel) wouldn't work because of the equations and images. What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: did you try the "paste from Word" button from the toolbar? or saving the document as HTML in Word, then copy the HTML code in WP?

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 separate issues here

1. Word -> Wordpress: As @One Trick Pony said, the easiest way to sort this will be using the Paste from Word button on the post editing toolbar. Images will probably need to be inserted manually
2. MathType -> WordPress: You'll need to install the [Latex for WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latex/) and use MathType to export the equations out in a standard Latex format - see [this post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latex/) for how to do it.

If you don't have MathType, I believe there are some tools you can find online and download that will convert MathType to Latex

Comment: Note: LaTeX is now part of the JetPack Plugin. I'd recommend using the JP-bundled version.

Comment: I`m not so sure about the JetPack bundled, its available as a standalone so why install a bunch of plugins which you don't need? And don't get me started on what i think of the move by automatic to include it in wordpress.